# Accessing S3 bucket from EC2 and from On-premises through VPC interface endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, interface, amazon-vpc, endpoint

Unable to access S3 bucket through Interface endpoint from EC2 instance.

I have created a VPC and single private subnet with EC2 instance and Interface endpoint. I have S3 bucket in same region. Though the EC2 and endpoint are in same same subnet and EC2 with IAM role to access full S3 bucket it still can't able to reach the S3 bucket. In reachability analyzer from instance to endpoint it is unreachable. where am i going wrong?

Comment: Please, verify that your DNS can resolve the S3 endpoints. Run the following commands:
`nslookup s3.amazonaws.com`
and:
`ping s3.amazonaws.com`
posting the results.

Answer (score 0):

How about route table of the subnet? In your explanation, you didn’t refer to route table, so it can be a possible issue.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html#associate-route-tables-s3